# Testing 2 consecutive client requests in Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

In Symfony2, I want to test a controller action with 2 subsequent requests if it behaves properly.
The first request will analyze the database and take appropriate action, the second request will also analyze the database and take a different action.

My code goes as follows:

```php
protected function setUp() {
    $this->_client = static::createClient();
    $kernel = static::$kernel;
    $kernel->boot();
    $this->_em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
    $this->_em->beginTransaction();
}

public function testAddToCartWith2Posts() {
    $this->addObjects(); // Initialize the database
    $object = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('BaseBundle:Object')->findAll()[0];
    $id = $object->getId();

    $crawler = $this->_client->request('POST', '/cart/add/' . $id);
    $crawler = $this->_client->request('POST', '/cart/add/' . $id);

    $session = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('session');
    $cart = $session->get('cart');
    $this->assertEquals($session->getId(), $cart->getSession());
    $this->assertEquals(2, count($cart->getCartItems()));        
}
```

The first request is able to read the list of objects. The second request is not.
The database becomes empty between requests. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you use a transaction?

Comment: @skler It doesn't show here, but in the tear down, I rollback so the other tests are not affected.

Comment: I guess that is better to configure a test database in /app/config/config_test.yml, maybe with sqlite3. The problem of the db empty could exist due the use of transaction.